# Flag icon beside logged in user

Tags: php, country-flag-icons

How to add Flag icons next to logged in username in navbar?

Using Php oop MySQL database on a signup/login system. I have users_country as one of my database columns. This is put in the table as the classic two letter format, example: Netherlands is stored as NL.

After a user logs in I have my nav bar change from sign up, sign in
to usercountry & username, logout

I do that with php

```php
Session start ()

echo $_SESSION[“usercountry”]
echo $_SESSION[“useruid”] (their username)
```

Now my navbar reads, example:
NLtestuser, logout

How do I go about replacing just the NL country code next to the username in the navbar to be an icon with the corresponding flag.
I would like the user to log in and the flag they selected upon signup will show instead of the flags two digit id.

I already have a flagicons folder in img folder in the root folder that contains all the flag icons with their corresponding countryid.png, example: nl.png

What is the simplest way to just change the country code to the icon flag when the user is logged in?
Thanks.

Comment: It is weird that you have a nav bar and a whole signup and login system in PHP OOP, yet you're struggling with showing an image in a web page? Anyway, in PHP it would be something like `<img src="/img/<?php echo strtolower($_SESSION[“usercountry”]); ?>.png" alt="flag">`, or in fully PHP code: `echo '<img src="/img/' . strtolower($_SESSION[“usercountry”]) . '.png" alt="flag">';`

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I understand you but for some reason it won't show up the image. I can't figure out why it doesnt work. the strtolower($_SESSION["usercountry"]) successfully changes the NL to nl to fit in the full php echo img src you recommended... its like plugging in the missing part to the .png but it's not working on my end... nothing shows on the page. It even made the logout and user part of the navbar disappear now.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you put the actual code, that is not working for you, in your question. That way it is easier for us to see what's wrong with it. Otherwise the only thing left for us is guessing.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware  This is the code in the navbar  `<ul class="left-side">

 <?php
     if(isset($_SESSION["userid"]))
     {
   ?>
    <li><a href='Signin.php'><?php echo $_SESSION["useruid"];?></a></li>
    <li><a href="includes/logout.inc.php" class="header-login-a">logout</a></li>
   <?php
     }
     else
     {
   ?>
     <li><a href='Signin.php'>Sign in</a></li>
     <li><a href='signup.php'>Sign up</a></li>
   <?php
     }
   ?>
  </ul>` when I tried to add your suggestion to this code, it didn't appear and items in the navbar & site body disappeared...

Comment: I don't think putting code in a comment like this is very helpful, that's why I asked you to put if in your question. However, I extracted the code from your comment, and reformatted it. Let me put the code I suggested in it an create an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your code reformatted, with the code to show the flag:

```php-template
<ul class="left-side"> 
<?php 
  if(isset($_SESSION["userid"])) { 
?> 
<li><img src="/img/<?php echo strtolower($_SESSION["usercountry"]); ?>.png" alt="flag"></li> 
<li><a href="includes/logout.inc.php" class="header-login-a">logout</a></li> 
<?php
  } else { 
?>
<li><a href='Signin.php'>Sign in</a></li> 
<li><a href='signup.php'>Sign up</a></li> 
<?php 
  } 
?>
</ul>
```

Have a look at what the HTML source looks like if the image doesn't show up.